# How should I escape this JavaScript regex (RFC 2822 email validator)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex:

```
/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
```

And I'm escaping the slashes like so:

```
/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
```

This seems to work fine, but I'm concerned that I'm missing an edge case and that the regex is broken by doing this. Is this the proper way to escape slashes?

Or should I instead declare with `new` like so:

```
var re = new RegExp(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/);
```

The JavaScript executes correctly without the slashes escaped (in Chrome), but it messes with my editor's (TextMate's) syntax highlighting. On further testing, even `new` doesn't eliminate the syntax highlighting issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to escape a forward slash in a JavaScript regex literal is with a backslash:

```
// unescaped:
some/string
// escaped in regex literal:
/some\/string/
```

There's no edge case that I'm aware of, and you should get an error if you don't do it.

When you use `new RegExp()` you're supposed to pass it a string, not a regex object, that is you should use the form `new RegExp("/[a-z0- etc")` - which should fix the syntax highlighting, but note of course that string literals also have characters that need to be escaped, including all backslashes. Given how often backslashes are used in regular expressions this means the string form is pretty ugly so it's generally used only where the regex expression needs to be built dynamically.